# import pymc error: global name 'channel' is not defined

Tags: python, pymc

OS: Win10 64x

IDE: Visual Studio 2017 Community

Python Environment: Anaconda 4.4.0 (Python 2.7)

When I try to import pymc, there is always an error:
[image: The error]

*NameError: global name 'channel' is not defined*

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc
tau = pymc.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=100)
print tau.random()
```

Then the error occurs. I installed the *pymc* module by Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: I have run the same codes in *spyder*. No error occurred.

Comment: idem: I get no error (mac os 10.11, console, pymc installed via anaconda3)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1307
It seems they have a bug in debugger.py
It works for me